# Can't find my shaders (Obj-C++, ios, opengles2.0)

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I am at the point of trying to load my shaders, but I can't seem to find them in code. I'm copying them into the bundle, and they are right next to the executable, but I still can't find them. I'm writing the rendering code in C++.

Here's the main bundle...

[image: Here's the main bundle...]

and my code that will hopefully, some day, load the shader. I'm just trying to find it right now, which is why nothing is actually happening...

```
void RenderingEngine::ReadShader()
{
    char* buffer;
    long size;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("Shader.frag");

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "FILE NOT OPENED!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with file directories, but googling around tells me I can use getcwd to find the current working directory. That just returns '/' to me.  The main bundle path for the application is: /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/22751FB2-AE33-4C94-A42D-8AC9E939286F/SrrsBznz.app/

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Objective-C, then the standard way to open the files would be something like:

```
// get the path to the shader file, without having to duplicate logic about
// how the bundle is laid out from the OS
NSString *pathToShader = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader"
                                      ofType:@"Frag"];

// load the source from pathToShader by whatever means... probably you'd
// actually get a file URL above and use the relevant NSString method,
// but that's not necessarily helpful here
```

So you'd explicitly get the OS to tell you the path to your file given that it's in the main (application) bundle.

You instead seem to be assuming that the current working directory is set up to the resources area within the bundle (which in iOS is the same as the path to the executable but on OS X is separate), which I don't think is guaranteed anywhere.

Assuming you have some Objective-C code to set up the relevant UIKit stuff before you branch off into C++, you probably want to add something like:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
           changeCurrentDirectoryPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
```

To establish that you want wherever the main bundle has put its resources to be the current working directory.

Comment: If I can't figure out how to do it in C++, I'll end up doing this. Do you know any ways I can accomplish the same thing in C++? Thanks either way!

Comment: @TNTisCOOL You can use objc to get the path, and do the rest in c++.

Comment: As rasmus implies, I don't think there's any direct C or C++ way to obtain the resource path. If you wanted to work that way around, you'd probably want to add a quick CompatibilityLayer.m or something that declares something like the C function `char *GetResourcePath()` and returns `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] UTF8String]`, then use that function from your C++. Just leave CompatibilityLayer.h as a normal C-style header.